# Load particular category by using collection

Tags: magento-1.9

I am new to magento , now I am trying to load particular category instead of using **load->** , I need to used **getCollection()**.How I retrieve particular category collection.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing why you are trying to avoid the category model's load method or what you want to use to filter your collection it's hard to give a better answer, but here are some methods for loading a category collection which filters on an array of category ID's or a category name.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
// From here it really depends on how you want to set up your SELECT statement
$collection->addIdFilter($ids_array);
// OR
$collection->addFieldToFilter('name', ['eq' => $category_name]);
```

Comment: @Mahesh1343 happy to help. If you need more help with it let me know.